# Confused about drawing a rectangle in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I want to draw a rectangle on a canvas in WPF. For drawing a line I can do this:

```
line.X1 = ls.P0.X;
line.Y1 = ls.P0.Y;
line.X2 = ls.P1.X;
line.Y2 = ls.P1.Y;          

MyCanvas.Children.Add(line);
```

...in other words the location is a **property of the line itself**.   I want to draw a rectangle the same way, i.e., assign its coordinates and add it to my canvas.  But the examples I've seen online so far seem to look like this:

```
rect = new Rectangle
{
    Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
    StrokeThickness = 2
};
Canvas.SetLeft(rect,startPoint.X);
Canvas.SetTop(rect,startPoint.X);
canvas.Children.Add(rect);
```

...in other words it doesn't look like the rectangle has an inherent location, but instead its location is set by calling a method of Canvas.  Is this true -  Lines have inherent coordinates but Rectangles do not?  Is there any way to have a rectangle in WPF with an inherent location, like a line, or do I have to roll my own (using lines)?

Comment: Use a Path with a RectangleGeometry.

Comment: The examples I've seen online of doing this in C#  - creating a path, creating a RectangleGeometry, creating a GeometryGroup, etc, make it look more complicated and overkill than just drawing 4 lines.   Is my initial assumption -  that lines have inherent location but rectangles don't, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Path` control with a `RectangleGeometry` like this:

```
var rect = new Path
{
    Data = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(x, y, width, height)),
    Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
    StrokeThickness = 2
};
canvas.Children.Add(rect);
```

Comment: Thank you!  That **is** simpler than the other examples I've seen online.  So is my underlying assumption correct -  that WPF Lines have inherent coordinates but Rectangles don't?  That seems inconsistent on Microsoft's part.

Comment: Sure, but you could still *also* set `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` on a Line control.

Comment: Some shapes like `Line` do expose coordinates, but those coordinates are relative to the shape itself (and not the parent element).  Depending on your situation, this may or may not be significant.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: @Clemens The comment wasn't directed at you; I'm sure you *are* aware.  I left the comment because it directly relates to OP's follow-up question, and to serve as a sort of 'breadcrumb' to future readers in the event that more answers show up here.

Answer (score 0):

> ...in other words it doesn't look like the rectangle has an inherent location, but instead its location is set by calling a method of Canvas. Is this true - Lines have inherent coordinates but Rectangles do not?

Locations in WPF are relative, which begs the question: coordinates **relative to what?**

`Line`, `Rectangle`, and `Path` all inherit from `Shape`, and in the case of any `Shape` object, the coordinates of the defining geometry are relative to the top-left corner of the `Shape` itself.  Thus, when you create a `Line` object from `(100, 300)` to `(300, 100)`, the resulting element is `300x300` points in size, even though the visible line has bounds of `200x200`:

[image: Line Diagram]

In this case, it is unnecessary to place the `Line` within a `Canvas`, as you are not using the coordinate system of the `Canvas`.

Some shapes like `Line` and `Path` allow you to place geometry at any "internal" coordinates you like.  Others, like `Rectangle` and `Ellipse`, always position their defining geometry at `(0, 0)` internally, forcing you to use other layout properties to position the shapes within the greater scene (e.g., `Canvas.Top/Left`, `Margin`, etc.).

In your example, if you were to define a `Rectangle` of `200x200` points, and use the `Canvas` attached properties to position the rectangle at `(100, 100)`, the resulting `Rectangle` element would measure `200x200`, while the parent `Canvas` would measure itself to be at least `300x300`, which is arguably more intuitive:

[image: Diagram 1]
<sub>*(shading added for clarity)*</sub>

You are correct in that this is rather inconsistent.  You may find it useful to always use layout properties (e.g., `Canvas.Left/Top`) to position shapes within a scene such that all elements are using the same coordinate system.